# How do I make GitLab Runner stop behaving like Linux when running on macOS?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I installed GitLab Runner on a macOS machine. I am using Docker as the executor with the image `node:6.11.2-slim`.

When I run `uname -a` locally in the terminal I get the following response:

> Darwin 1-MacBook-Pro 16.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.7.0: Thu Jun 15 17:36:27 PDT 2017; root:xnu-3789.70.16~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

However running that same command as part of a GitLab pipeline on the runner returns:

> Linux runner--project-0-concurrent-0 4.9.87-linuxkit-aufs #1 SMP Wed Mar 14 15:12:16 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Because of this, my build process is failing because it expects the OS to be macOS -- not Linux.

How do I make GitLab Runner/Docker not behave like Linux?

Comment: I may be confusing things, but if that command is running from inside the Docker container, IT IS running on Linux, isn't it? You will probably have to pass environment variables or build arguments to get it to act differently. (Note, I have never used this setup, I am only using logical extrapolation from working with Docker containers. I may be completely wrong on this.)

Comment: @mrunion: You are right. I was under the impression that Docker on Mac runs a Mac VM, but it uses Linux. Hence what I am doing is not possible. It seems like the only options are to use GitLab Runner's "SSH" or "Shell" executors to compile on darwin.

Answer (score 1):

See comments.

I was under the impression that Docker on Mac runs a Mac VM, but it uses Linux. Hence what I am doing is not possible. It seems like the only options are to use GitLab Runner's "SSH" or "Shell" executors to compile on darwin.